# auth login instanceurl with parameter

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When I directly go to the url https://test.salesforce.com/?un=test%40example.com.sbname (using `@` instead of `%40` works as well) from a browser, sandbox login page opens up with prefilled username value `test@example.com.sbname`.

[image]

If I use the command,

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com/?un=test%40example.com.sbname
```

login page opens up with additional text

[image]

Is there a way to do prevent/remove those added parameters and open a sandbox login page just like the first example?

Comment: Instead of passing it through the instance URL, what happens if you use the `--setdefaultusername` parameter instead

Comment: @BryanAnderson `--setdefaultusername` doesn't accept any argument and looking at its description, I am not sure if I can use that for my case. `Sets the authenticated org as the default username that all commands run against.`

Comment: Can you try `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com/?un=test%40example.com.sbname&`

Comment: @TusharSharma For windows command line, works as the same and Powershell doesn't allow ampersand. Using `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r "https://test.salesforce.com/?un=test%40example.com.sbname&"` in powershell also resulted as above.

Comment: @Lafexlos Why do you want to accomplish this in the first place?  Could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) situation here

Comment: @BrianMiller Nothing urgent or too important actually. I was looking through the readme file I 
created for sfdx usage since there will be a new hire for SF in our company and I was wondering if I can automate that login process via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The `-r` or `--instanceurl` param is just supposed to point to the right endpoint environment. I don't think you can achieve what you're looking for within the CLI command itself.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_auth.htm) for `auth:web:login` doesn't give URL param options as an example, nor suggests that this could be done

> `-r` | `--instanceurl` INSTANCEURL
>   *Optional*
>   - The login URL of the Salesforce instance that the org lives on.